# Flutter pass data to multiple pages

Tags: flutter, constructor

I'm building multiple (different) UI pages with the same constructor. I'm using a statelful widget as my constructor and in my constractor I get user info data from Firestore. I want to to pass the Firebase data to the different admin UI screens from the constructor.

**my constructor**

```
class MyConstructor extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Map<String, dynamic> userDetails) navigationCallback;
  
  const MyConstructor(
      {super.key,
      required this.navigationCallback,
      });

  @override
  State<MyConstructor> createState() => _MyConstructorState();
}

class _MyConstructorState extends State<MyConstructor> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream:
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionPath").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return 
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                 Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                widget.navigationCallback(
                                                    widget.navigationCallback(snapshot.data!.docs[index] as Map<String,
                                                        dynamic>)));
                    
                  },
                  /*the rest of the code*/
                );
                },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**class to access the contructor**

```
class MyMainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyMainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyMainPage> createState() => _MyMainPageState();
}

class _MyMainPageState extends State<MyMainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MyConstructor(
      navigationCallback: (Map<String, dynamic> userDetails) { 
  return UserPage(userDetails: userDetails)));
   }
    );
  }
}
```

**Page to access the data**

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserPage({super.key, required this.userDetails});
       Map<String, dynamic> userDetails;

  @override
  State<UserPage> createState() => _UserPageState();
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  /*how do I access the data from previous page*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I should tell you to study 2 things

1st -> State management -> Provider, bloc, getX etc ( this will tell you how to manage state ) -> This is the most recommended way to handle data/state across your application.

2nd -> Create a route generator class which will handle all the navigation and  with that you can also pass related data to each screen.

Comment: Will either of them work or I have to combine the two?

Comment: Both go hand in hand and are recommended for big complex projects. I have some source code which you can take inspirations from, but we have to hop on a call to discuss that as I cannot share the source code of my big projects.